# AttributeError: module 'xlwings' has no attribute 'load'

Tags: excel, pandas, xlwings

I am on Windows 10, Python 3.8.5, xlwings-0.23.0

I am trying to load a selected range of cells in Excel into Pandas DataFrame.
I am following documentation on:
https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.load

```
xlwings.load(index=1, header=1)
```

Loads the selected cell(s) of the active workbook into a pandas DataFrame. If you select a single cell that has adjacent cells, the range is auto-expanded and turned into a pandas DataFrame. If you don’t have pandas installed, it returns the values as nested lists.

Parameters:
`index (bool or int, default 1)` – Defines the number of columns on the left that will be turned into the DataFrame’s index

`header (bool or int, default 1)` – Defines the number of rows at the top that will be turned into the DataFrame’s columns

Examples

```
import xlwings as xw
xw.load()
```

My script has selected relevant cells through this command:

```
wb.sheets['myTab'].range('C5').expand().select()
```

I am now trying to load those cells into Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = xw.load()
```

I am getting this error message:
**AttributeError: module 'xlwings' has no attribute 'load'**

Also tried:

```
wb = xw.Book(strMyExcelFile)
wb.sheets[strTab].activate()
df = wb.load()
```

In that case the error message is: **AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'load'**

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to pass selected cells into Pandas DataFrame, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case resolved with the following solution:

Open Excel file and select a target tab.

```
wb = xw.Book(strMyExcelFile)
wb.sheets[strMyTab].activate()
```

Critical issue #1: Need to define the range of selected cells to use downstream.

Select a starting cell, C5 in this case, and all adjacent cells.

```
cellRange = sheet.range('C5').expand()
```

Critical issue #2: Assign data from the selected range into Pandas DataFrame.

This is what I was trying to solve for earlier but issue #1 is a pre-requisite.
The first row in Excel file is headers.

```
df = wb.sheets[strMyTab].range(cellRange).options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=True).value
```

Close Excel file without saving it.

```
wb.close()
```

Note: Credits due to suggestions received here https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1555

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to name the Python file the same as any of the modules being imported in that Python file.

i figured it out from this https://geektechstuff.com/2020/06/13/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-has-no-attribute-python/